# Horizontal vs Vertical sides Exit from a Rectangle for simple symmetric Random Walk on $\textbf{Z}^{2}$

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, random-walks, martingales, random-permutations

Consider simple symmetric random walk, $X_{n} = (X_{n}^{(1)}, X_{n}^{(2)})$ with $X_0= (0,0)$, on the 2 dimensional integer lattice, $\textbf{Z}^{2}$.

Let $T_{M}, T_{N}$  be the smallest $n$ such that $|X_{n}^{(1)}| = M$ and 
$|X_{n}^{(2)}| = N$ respectively, where $|\cdot|$ denotes  absolute value and  $M,N$ are positive integers.

What is the $P(\min\{T_{M},T_{N}\} = T_{M})$ ?

Of course, if $M = N$ the answer is just 1/2. But how does this extend to the general case?

Further, considering $[-M,M] ×[-1,1]$, I can calculate this probability exactly by noting that $X_{n}$ can hit either one of the vertical sides prior to the horizontal ones if and only if no vertical jump occurs for time equal (in distribution) to the exit time from $[−M,M]$ for a 1-D RW.

Comment: When you say the answer is just $1/2$ for $M=N$, this means the probability that $T_M = T_N$ is $0$. Are you considering a Brownian motion instead of a random walk, then? For a Brownian motion, you can compute the probability by taking a Riemann map from the rectangle to the unit disk so that the origin is fixed, and then the probability of exiting through the horizontal sides is the proportion of the circle taken up by the image of the sides. See harmonic measure.

Comment: Is this a discrete walk on $\mathbb{Z}^2$?

Comment: Arguments of this type (showing that this probability is bounded away from 0 if the ratio of $M$ and $N$ is bounded) are used by Bollobas and Riordan in their book on percolation theory.

Comment: @John Lotos: The change you made did not affect whether there are ties which make the probability greater than $1/2$. You can rule those out with a random walk whose steps are $(0,\pm 1),(\pm 1,0)$ rather than a product of random walks in each coordinate. Is that what you mean? Either way, the probability for Brownian motion (say, $0.9774$ for a $1 \times 3$ rectangle) is the limit of the probabilities for random walks with $M/N \to 3$ as $N \to \infty$.

Comment: @Douglas Zare: I consider simple symmetric 2 dimensional RW confined on a rectangle grid (or, equivalently, the set of sites of $Z^{2}$ within the rectangle $[-M,M] \times [-N,N]$). Simple symmetric means that jumps to every neighbor site occur with probability 1/4. (or, if you like to think of two independent 1-dimensional RW, simply toss a fair coin at every step to decide in which direction (vertical or horizontal) you move)

Comment: @Antony Quas: Can you please give a more specific reference (e.g. pages, chapter etc) ? I don't see what percolation theory might have to do with that, so can you please remember where you have seen this playing out? Many thanks!

Comment: @DouglasZare. Please give a specific reference regarding the result you claim to be somewhat relevant. I am not sure what is meant by "either way", are you suggesting that my problem is equivalent to that of considering two independent RW in the limit ? Can you also give a reference or elaborate regarding this claim?

Comment: In the case of a $3 \times N$ rectangle I can calculate this probability exactly, simply by noting that the only way this RW would hit either one of the vertical sides first is that of no vertical movement for time equal in distribution  to the exit time from $[-N,N]$ for the 1-D RW.

Comment: Which of the results? The limiting connection between random walks and Brownian motion, or the solution of the problem for Brownian motion? Or that the limit of random walks in the directions $(0,\pm1), (\pm1,0)$ is the same as $(\pm1,\pm1)$? By the way, I didn't say the $3\times N$ rectangles with $N \to \infty$ were relevant, but rather the rectangles with $\frac{M}{N} \to 3$ as $N \to \infty$. You get one approximation of the Brownian motion on a $3 \times 1$ rectangle with a random walk on a $30 \times 10$ grid, a better one on a $3000 \times 1000$ grid, etc.

Comment: @DouglasZare
The solution of the problem for Brownian Motion would certainly be a helpful pointer. Then, the connection among the two problems as well would be useful, though for this i am guessing you use the quantile or dyadic coupling. Many thanks.